# Difference between interpolate methods in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I've been trying to branch out with Inkscape and have been experimenting with the interpolate extension. One thing I cannot work out is what the difference between the two interpolation methods is. I've looked at various tutorials/'documentation' and the most they say is that they're simply different.

[image: Interpolate method 1]
[image: Interpolate method 2]

The example on the left uses interpolation method 1, on the right uses interpolation 2. I can see that in method 1, the bottom line seems to map onto only about 90% of the top line. In method 2, the top line smoothly maps to all of the bottom line.

But what are these methods actually specifying? The order that I select the lines makes no difference so I'm unsure what is happening here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In newer versions of Inkscape (1.2+), the setting in the dialog is much more descriptive:

[image: Interpolate dialog in version 1.2.2 of Inkscape]

It controls how to handle paths with different node counts. Either rearrange and add nodes or cut the paths to the length of the shorter reference path. One is more "complete" the other maybe a little more accurate.

[image: Example interpolation between paths with different node counts with both values of the method setting.]

In your own example above you can see for the left one the generated paths are just cut short to the right.

Comment: Thank you so much (my bad, hadn't updated in a far while). I suspected it was just in which order the paths were mapped, but this is very helpful thanks!